# Taking device screenshot while application is close

Tags: android, background, screenshot

I know this question is ask number of times but wait i am asking something different.

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/1139398) post and able to take screen shot. but is it possible to take screen shot when my application is closed.

Supposed i set timer like after 1 hour and i close my app. Then exactly after 1 hour device need to take a screen shot whatever on a screen.

Is this possible with [Background Services](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)?

I already follow code and also did some research but is this possible?
Is it necessary to root device to take screenshot.

Please give me any hint or reference.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't, as that would allow you to read a user's passwords.

Comment: is this not possible? if we do some work in background then why it's not possible to take a screenshot? Can you elaborate?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using : call the methods in this library from service.

http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/

Android Screenshot Library (ASL) enables to programmatically capture screenshots from Android devices without requirement of having root access privileges. Instead, ASL utilizes a native service running in the background, started via the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) once per device boot.

[DeveloperGuide](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/DeveloperGuide)

**UPDATE:**

The method mentioned in your reference will not work in that case, as it reads the view that are drawn and in application context. where as if application is closed then you cant get that context.( at-least on non rooted phone).

On rooted device you can read complete frame-buffer so no need to worry about the application context.

I did tried to use the ASL once and it worked out good for me.

Comment: I have tried it but it says aslProvider is not available. why?

Comment: you need to copy asl-native and start it. not sure if it will still work. Check Here https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-screenshot-library/issues